# Why doesn't this cause stackoverflow?

Tags: haskell, recursion, stack-overflow

In `8.hs` I define

```
digitProduct [] = 1
digitProduct (c:rest) = (read [c] :: Int) * digitProduct rest
```

Then inside `ghci`, I run

```
digitProduct $ take 10000 $ repeat '9'
```

And it produces a result:

```
-3633723290617080191
```

I would've imagined that a recursion of 10000 would've caused a stackoverflow. Also, my recursion isn't a tail call. What's going on here?

Comment: Not all implementation of all programming languages use a fixed-size stack to allocate call frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing special is going on. 10,000 is just not enough to fill the stack. I get a stack overflow in `ghci` when I replace `take 10000` with `take 100000000`.